# click event in modal popup does not get fired

Tags: asp.net

i have inquiry form which gets open in modal popup extender. when i click on button to store data click event does not get fired
i don't know whats going wrong can any one help me to solve this problem
thanks in advance

here is my code

DefaultMaster.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DefaultMasterPage.master.cs"
    Inherits="DefaultMasterPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../JyotiInstitute/Styles/StyleSheet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../JyotiInstitute/Styles/sliderman.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../JyotiInstitute/Styles/style1.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../JyotiInstitute/Styles/style2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/sliderman.1.3.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/easytabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/modernizr.custom.04022.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('#toTop').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#toTop').fadeOut();
                }
            });

            $('#toTop').click(function () {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
                return false;
            });

        });

        $(function () {
            $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function () {
                $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');
            },
     4000);

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div id="absolute">
            <div id="div1" class="div1">
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/sef111.png" Style="margin-top: 10px;
                    margin-left: 5px" ID="OpenPopUp1" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="OpenPopUp1_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp1" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="div2">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="OpenPopUp2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/scef1.png" Style="margin-top: 2px;"
                    CausesValidation="false" OnClick="OpenPopUp2_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp2" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnPopUp1" CancelControlID="btnClose1">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
            <center>
                <div class="outer_div">
                    <div class="inner_div">
                        <h1>
                            Student Enquiry Form</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text=" Your enquiry sent successfully..." ID="ltrMsg1"
                            Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Fileds marked with * are mandatory"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <center>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCourses" runat="server" CssClass="select">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtName" WatermarkText="* Full Name ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEmail" WatermarkText="* E-mail ID ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="+91" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="textbox"
                                            Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMobile" CssClass="textbox" Width="172px"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMobile" WatermarkText="* Mobile number ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender6" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCity" WatermarkText="City ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtState" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtState" WatermarkText="State ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComments" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textboxMulti"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                            ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender7" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtComments" WatermarkText="Comments ">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <br />
                                        <center>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="btnConrol" 
                                                onclick="btnSave_Click" />

                                        </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select course"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="drpCourses" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />--%>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter full name"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtName" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email-ID"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" runat="server"
                                CssClass="ErrorMsg" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" /><br />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter mobile number"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Images/close1.png" runat="server" ID="btnClose1" Style="float: right;
                margin-top: -645px; margin-right: -20px;" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender_2" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            PopupControlID="Panel2" TargetControlID="btnPopUp2" CancelControlID="btnClose2">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
            <center>
                <div class="outer_div">
                    <div class="inner_div">
                        <h1>
                            Institute Enquiry Form</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text=" Your enquiry sent successfully..." ID="ltrMsg2"
                            Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Fileds marked with * are mandatory"></asp:Label><br />
                        <br />
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFullName" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender8" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFullName" WatermarkText="* Full Name ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailId" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender9" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEmailId" WatermarkText="* E-mail ID ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="+91" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="textbox"
                                        Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMobileNum" CssClass="textbox" Width="172PX"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender10" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMobileNum"
                                        WatermarkText="* Mobile number ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCityName" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender11" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCityName"
                                        WatermarkText="City ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStateName" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender12" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStateName"
                                        WatermarkText="State ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPin" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender14" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtPin" WatermarkText="Pin Code ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textboxMulti"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender
                                        ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender13" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtComment" WatermarkText="Comments ">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <br />
                                    <center>
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnStore" Text="Save" CssClass="btnConrol" 
                                            onclick="btnStore_Click" />

                                    </center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be left blank"
                            SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtFullName" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be left blank"
                            SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                            runat="server" CssClass="ErrorMsg" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" /><br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be left blank"
                            SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtMobileNum" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Images/close1.png" runat="server" ID="btnClose2" Style="float: right;
                margin-top: -630px; margin-right: -20px;" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <div id="head-wrap">
            <div id="back-wrap">
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#">News </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">E-Prospectus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test.aspx">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-container">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <div id="logo_hm">
                        <div id="hm_outer">
                            <a href="Index.aspx">
                                <img alt="" src="Images/hm.png" style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 4px; border-radius: 5px" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab_outer">
                        <div id="MainMenu">
                            <center>
                                <ul id="nav">
                                    <li style="display: inline"><a href="Index.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                    <li style="display: inline; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><a href="AboutUs.aspx"><span>About
                                        Us</span></a> </li>
                                    <li style="display: inline"><a href="#"><span>Academics</span></a>
                                        <ul class="nav first">
                                            <li><a href="Overview.aspx">Overview</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Ordinances.aspx">Ordinances & Regulations</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Programmes.aspx">Programmes</a> </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="display: inline; width: 100px"><a href="#"><span>Study Centers</span></a>
                                        <ul class="nav first">
                                            <li><a href="#">Join As Study Center</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="display: inline"><a href="#"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div id="search-box">
                            <div id="searchwrapper">
                                <form action="">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="searchbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearch"
                                    WatermarkText="Courses, Study Centers">
                                </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                <%-- <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/search1.png"
                                    CssClass="searchbox_submit"  PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx" />--%>
                                <a href="Search.aspx">
                                    <img alt="" src="Images/search1.png" class="searchbox_submit" /></a>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle-wrap">
            <div id="left">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img alt="" src="Images/Jyoti_logo .jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <div id="slider">
                        <div id="Div3" class="fadein">
                            <img src="Images/c1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <img src="Images/c2.jpg" alt="" />
                            <img src="Images/c3.jpg" alt="" />
                            <img src="Images/c4.jpg" alt="" />
                            <img src="Images/c5.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="SliderName_3Description">
                            <span>Jyoti Institute of IT & Management</span>
                            <br />
                            <span style="text-transform: none; font-size: 14px">Jaunpur (UP)</span>
                        </div>
                        <%--  <div class="slider">
                            <center>
                                <div id="slider_container_3">
                                    <div id="SliderName_3">
                                        <img alt="" src="Images/c1.jpg" />
                                        <img alt="" src="Images/c2.jpg" />
                                        <img alt="" src="Images/c3.jpg" /><img alt="" src="Images/c5.jpg" />
                                        <img alt="" src="Images/c4.jpg" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="SliderName_3Description">
                                        <span>Jyoti Institute of IT & Management</span>
                                        <br />
                                        <span style="text-transform: none; font-size: 14px">Jaunpur (UP)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                           <script type="text/javascript">

                                demo3Effect1 = { name: 'myEffect31', top: true, move: true, duration: 400 };
                                demo3Effect2 = { name: 'myEffect32', right: true, move: true, duration: 400 };
                                demo3Effect3 = { name: 'myEffect33', bottom: true, move: true, duration: 400 };
                                demo3Effect4 = { name: 'myEffect34', left: true, move: true, duration: 400 };
                                demo3Effect5 = { name: 'myEffect35', rows: 3, cols: 9, delay: 50, duration: 100, order: 'random', fade: true };
                                demo3Effect6 = { name: 'myEffect36', rows: 2, cols: 4, delay: 100, duration: 400, order: 'random', fade: true, chess: true };

                                effectsDemo3 = [demo3Effect1, demo3Effect2, demo3Effect3, demo3Effect4, demo3Effect5, demo3Effect6, 'blinds'];

                                var demoSlider_3 = Sliderman.slider({ container: 'SliderName_3', width: 790, height: 300, effects: effectsDemo3,
                                    display: { autoplay: 3000 },
                                    description: { background: '#000000', opacity: 0.5, height: 30, position: 'bottom' }
                                });

                            </script>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Content-wrap">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="site-footer">
        <center>
            <span>&COPY; Copyrights, 2013 Jyoti Institute | Designed & Developed by Weblord Infotech</span>
        </center>
        <a href="#" id="toTop" class="nav_up"></a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


DefaultMaster.master.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class DefaultMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    Enquiry objEnquiry = new Enquiry();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void OpenPopUp1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }

    protected void OpenPopUp2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender_2.Show();
    }

    private void Clear()
    {
        drpCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtFullName.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtEmailId.Text = "";
        txtMobile.Text = "";
        txtMobileNum.Text = "";
        txtCity.Text = "";
        txtCityName.Text = "";
        txtState.Text = "";
        txtStateName.Text = "";
        txtPin.Text = "";
        txtComment.Text = "";
        txtComments.Text = "";

    }

    protected void btnStore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Studycenter enquiry form
        //objEnquiry.EnterStudyCenterEnquiry(0, txtFullName.Text, txtEmailId.Text, txtMobileNum.Text, txtCityName.Text, txtStateName.Text, txtPin.Text, txtComment.Text);
        ltrMsg2.Visible = true;
        Clear();
    }
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Student enquiry form
        //objEnquiry.EnterStudentEnquiry(0, drpCourses.SelectedItem.Text, txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtMobile.Text, txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtComments.Text);
        ltrMsg1.Visible = true;
        Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a request being submited to the server or is it not doing anything it all?
In the case of nothing happening my experience usually is a validationhandler that's invisible and blocking the call.
Try adding causesValidation="False" to your save button as a test to see if that is the issue
If it works without validation find the validator that's failing and fix it ! ;)

Comment: before adding causesValidation="False" in button it was not doing anything but when i added causesValidation="False" it just simply closes the modal popup without doing any task

Comment: When debugging test if you are hitting your page_load and your btnSave_Click method. Let me know the result :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Is your problem not solved then? The event was not firing due to the validation, we fixed the validation and the event is firing now. Handle the save in the event and go to the pub for a drink now, no?

Comment: No problem, enjoy the beer !

Comment: I need one too :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`. The reason behind this is explained here:

[Microsoft Docs on UseSubmitBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Button control uses the client browser's submit mechanism or the ASP.NET postback mechanism.

It appears that instead of trying to postback it was using the client browser submit so my code behind wasnt firing,